# how to get contract balance from bscscan and display it on my site

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js

hi so I'm new to web3 and I been trying  to display the balance of an smart contract on my site and make it auto refresh

I tried basically everything used the help of chatgpt still nothing

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I like to show you what I tried so far but unfortunately I'm not at my PC right now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.